# Sort nested objects by value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested object:

```
{
  "cases": {
    "7": {   
      "order": 4, 
      "current": false
    }, 
    "11": {
      "order": 1, 
      "current": true
    }, 
    "5": {
      "order": 2, 
      "current": false
    },
    "14": {
      "order": 3, 
      "current": false
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to sort the nested objects by `order` value. How can I do it?

Comment: while objects have actually no order, you could take the keys in an object and sort it and take it as wrapper for the access order.

Comment: You can attempt this but there is no guarantee of sequence of object properties regardless of how you create them. Only arrays hold a specific sequence.

Comment: You would have to create a mapping between indices in your object and their order, Rendering having that order value useless.

Comment: An easier solution would be to review your data structure.

Comment: It appears you're expecting someone to write code for you for free. [Please show that you've invested some of your own time into researching the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/497418). You can do this by including a [mcve] of what you've tried and what your expected output is, along with a detailed question about the specific issue you ran into.

Answer (score -1):

I would just work the object into an array, using the order value as the key.